# TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied options is not an object error when trying to ban someone

Tags: discord, discord.js

My ban command checks if a user is bannable then bans them. My kick does the same thing but it actually works. The ban message sends so the user is bannable but doesn't actually get banned. Here's my code

```js
if (memberTarget.bannable) {
            if (
              message.member.roles.highest.position >
              message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id).roles.highest.position
            ) {
              target.ban(reason);
              let banReason = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setDescription(`**${target.user.tag}** has been banned.`)
                .addField("Reason:", `${!reason ? "Unspecified" : `${reason}`}`)
                .setFooter(
                  `banned by ${message.author.tag}`,
                  "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/375020097431011328/881012463645126686/3dgifmaker15131.gif"
                )
                .setColor("#000000");
              message.reply({ embeds: [banReason] }).catch((err) => {
                message.channel.send({ embeds: [banReason] });
              });
            }
```

My problem with this is everytime I try to go and kick someone, I get my error:

```js
if (!memberTarget.bannable) {
            let lowPerms = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              .setDescription(
                `<:role:887134365476335626> I lack the required permission to ban **${target.user.tag}**.`
              )
              .setColor("#000000");
            message.reply({ embeds: [lowPerms] });
          }
```

This happens even why I try to kick someone with no roles and my bot had administrative permissions.
The actual error itself:

```cmd
C:\Users\\Documents\GitHub\omex\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildBanManager.js:142
    if (typeof options !== 'object') throw new TypeError('INVALID_TYPE', 'options', 'object', true);     
                                           ^

TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied options is not an object.
    at GuildBanManager.create (C:\Users\\Documents\GitHub\omex\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildBanManager.js:142:44)
    at GuildMemberManager.ban (C:\Users\\Documents\GitHub\omex\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildMemberManager.js:364:28)
    at GuildMember.ban (C:\Users\\Documents\GitHub\omex\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\GuildMember.js:299:31)
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\\Documents\GitHub\omex\commands\ban.js:32:22)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\\Documents\GitHub\omex\index.js:133:20)
    at Client.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\\Documents\GitHub\omex\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:23:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\\Documents\GitHub\omex\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\\Documents\GitHub\omex\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:345:31)  
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\\Documents\GitHub\omex\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:443:22) {        
  [Symbol(code)]: 'INVALID_TYPE'
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear as it is right now could you provide further details as in where the actual error originates ( the one in your title ) and the stacktrace for it?

Comment: Edited. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error attached in question is originated via this specific line:

```
target.ban(reason)
```

The [`GuildMember#ban([options])`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=ban) if needed to be called with options the options must be an array of options / object like so

```js
    target.ban({
        reason: `${!reason ? "Unspecified" : `${reason}`}`
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

NodeJS is freaking out because I'm guessing the `reason` you passed into `target.ban()` is a string, not an object. In discord.js, you have to provide an object into the `GuildMember#ban()` method, like this:

```js
target.ban({ reason });
```

You can also choose how many days (from 0-7) of messages to delete, like this:

```js
target.ban({ days: 7, reason }); // Deletes all messages the member banned sent within the past 7 days
```

Comment: I didn't know you could delete past messages too. Is there  a limit like 100 messages similar to `message.delete` and is there a way to display the author of the message in audit logs?

Comment: afaik there isn't a limit on how many messages can be deleted with a ban, just up to 7 days (also i don't know what you mean by displaying the author of the message in audit logs - the person banned is the person whose messages you're deleting)

Comment: **There is a limit!** Bots can only delete messages sent by an user upto 2 weeks iirc even without the option provided it defaults to 14 days

Comment: @chicken I meant like a `Banned by` message but I just added `reason: \`${!reason ? "unspecified" : \`${reason}\`} || by ${message.member.user.tag}\`` which shows the author in the reason. My only problem is the reason shows for my ban command but not my kick and I even tried copy and pasting the ban into the kick command and editing the code. Instead I get `[object Object]` for some reason.

Comment: @Zero wdym? the docs say that you can only delete up to 7 days, and that if you don't provide the option, it defaults to 0

Comment: @FallenHero that's because GuildMember#kick() doesn't take an object, it only takes a string, which is the reason. You use it like `target.kick(reason)`